# Django Array agregate on multiple fields

Tags: django, django-orm, django-postgresql

I am using postgres as my backedn in django Application

I have 4 models in my app

```
class sprint(models.model):
sprintname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
.....
```

```
class testcases(models.model):
testcasename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
sprint = models.ForiegnKeyField(sprint) 
.......
```

```
class tags(models.model)
tagname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
testcase = models.ForiegnKeyField(testcases)
```

```
class sprinttestcases(models.Model):
    sprint = models.Foriegnkey(sprint)
    testcase = model.Foriegnkey(testcase)
    tag = models.ForiegnKey(tags)
```

Using django templates , I am outputing these values in Ui on a sprint basis

Like below. Here the testcases and tags will be in drop downs

[image]

How to write django query to get data like this?

Tried these, but not sure on how to proceed.

```
q= SprintTestcases.objects.filter(something).\
            values('sprint_id','testcase_id').annotate(tmlist = ArrayAgg('tag'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of annotate, you can achieve same thing by serializer

```
#views.py
q= SprintTestcases.objects.filter(something)
serialized = SprintTestcasesSerializer(q, many=True)
return Response(serialized.data)

#serializers.py
class TagSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  tagname  = serializers.CharField()
class TestCaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  testcasename = serializers.CharField()
class SprintTestcasesSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
  sprint_name = serializer.CharField(source="sprint.sprintname")
  testcase = TestCaseSerializer()
  tag = TagSerializer()
```